# how do i publish a post at mid night using mysql event

Tags: mysql

First of all thanks in advance. i m creating a product management site in php .a concept of the site is to when a product post is inserted it will be activated and display at mid night and now i want tell something about a date-time(mysql table name is deals and its date column name is submit_date) formats 2013-04-05 13:15:43

```
CREATE EVENT deals
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '00:00:00' midnight

DO
update deals set status='1' where submit_date=CURDATE();
```

i have a confusion in midnight syntax means for example for every day we can write here 1 DAY as i want do something here for mid night for every inserted rows in deals table...

Comment: Don't send a boy to do a man's job: Use `crontab`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a start time (with date) and then use `EVERY 1 DAY`;

```
create event `update_deals`
    on schedule every 1 day
    starts '2013-06-30 00:00:00'
do
begin
    ...
end;
```

I think the start date & time must be in the future though.

Comment: ok but i want to update status='1' for every insert a post.then here u define starts '2013-06-30 00:00:00'. i want to know what is role of date here.is it to use to just start this function i m confuse in this line starts '2013-06-30 00:00:00'

Comment: @Neeraj, that date is when the schedule should start counting the `every 1 day` - so after this date the block of code will run every day at `00:00:00`. You should add your code where the `...` are.

Comment: OK means first time we need to define date after that it takes only 00:00:00 . it will be work for me. many many many thanks to you.